Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' - React
Getting error in React TypeScript: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'
I am getting this error for Child Component
In the child component Props is not working.
If I am using any in the child component props than it's working fine.
Below props type working with **any **
type Props = {
    handleClick?: any;
}

Props declared in child component that is not working
type Props = {
    handleClick?: (val: boolean) => void; // Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'
}

Parent Component
const RolesList = () => {
  const [addRoleModel, setAddRoleModel] = useState(false);

  const roleModel = (val: boolean) => {
    setAddRoleModel(val);
  }

  return (
    <LayoutDefault>
      <div className='roles-list-page'>
        {
          addRoleModel && <AddRole handleClick={roleModel} /> // Child component where I am getting error
        }
        <Head handleClick={roleModel} />
        <Data />
      </div>
    </LayoutDefault>
  )
}

Child Component
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
    handleClick?: (val: boolean) => void; 
}

const AddRole = ({handleClick}:Props) => {
    const handleRoleClick = () => {
        handleClick(false);  // Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="relative z-10" aria-labelledby="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">

                <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true"></div>

                <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 w-screen overflow-y-auto">
                    <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">

                        <div className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg">
                            <div className="bg-white p-5">

                                <h2 className="text-base font-semibold text-lg" id="modal-title">
                                    Add New Role
                                </h2>

                                <div className="mt-2">

                                    <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                                        <label htmlFor="first-name" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Name</label>
                                        <div className="">
                                            <input type="text" name="first-name" id="first-name" autoComplete="given-name" className="border border-gray-300 rounded block w-full pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2 outline-0" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="col-span-full mt-2">
                                        <label htmlFor="about" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Description</label>
                                        <div className="">
                                            <textarea id="about" name="about" className="border border-gray-300 rounded block w-full pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2 outline-0"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mt-2 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">

                                        <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                                            <label htmlFor="first-name" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Type *</label>
                                            <div className="mt-2">
                                                <select id="country" name="country" className="border border-gray-300 rounded block w-full pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2 outline-0">
                                                    <option selected>Select</option>
                                                    <option>One</option>
                                                    <option>Two</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                                            <label htmlFor="last-name" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Company</label>
                                            <div className="mt-2">
                                                <select id="country" name="country" className="border border-gray-300 rounded block w-full pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2 outline-0">
                                                    <option selected>Select</option>
                                                    <option>One</option>
                                                    <option>Two</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mt-2 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6">

                                        <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                                            <label htmlFor="first-name" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Accessible Modules *</label>
                                            <div className="mt-2">
                                                <select id="country" name="country" className="border border-gray-300 rounded block w-full pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2 outline-0">
                                                    <option selected>Select</option>
                                                    <option>One</option>
                                                    <option>Two</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="sm:col-span-3">
                                            <label htmlFor="last-name" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Available Actions *</label>
                                            <div className="mt-2">
                                                <select id="country" name="country" className="border border-gray-300 rounded block w-full pt-1 pb-1 pl-2 pr-2 outline-0">
                                                    <option selected>Select</option>
                                                    <option>One</option>
                                                    <option>Two</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div className="mt-6 flex items-center justify-end gap-x-6">
                                        <button type="submit" className="rounded-2xl px-7 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white bg-gray-600 ">Save</button>
                                        <button type="button" className="rounded-md px-7 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 bg-gray-300" onClick={handleRoleClick}>Cancel</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default AddRole;

Please help me to fix this bug.

I'm not seeing any reason for you to define the handleClick as optional. Why do you have it like that?

Use the optional chaining (?.) operator when invoking the function which short-circuits instead of throwing an error if the reference is undefined or null.
const handleRoleClick = () => {
     handleClick?.(false);   // ✅ 
}

